# Loading large Javascript array via AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I need to pass a javascript array to a function...

```
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

...but I want to load the array on demand through ajax and I have my server side file formatted as...

```
[
  0,
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4
]
```

I need it to perform as few calculations as possible on the client side as the arrays will be huge so I formatted it as such. However I seem to be misunderstanding something about JSON because it says that it's invalid JSON on the client side once it makes the ajax request.

How can I load a very large array via ajax without any (or VERY minimal) client side processing?

**EDIT**
It's for a Google Maps heatmap layer. This is an example from their site on how I should be passing it to the function client side:

```
[
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782745, -122.444586),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782842, -122.443688),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782919, -122.442815),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.782992, -122.442112),
  new google.maps.LatLng(37.783100, -122.441461)
]
```

I replaced the data with raw numbers in my example to keep the question simplified. I want to load that array directly using an ajax request. There will be multiple heatmaps the user can view via toggle buttons.

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly your client side function needs to do?

Comment: Geolocation data for a Google Maps heatmap layer. Each entry in the array is a location.

Comment: "it says that it's invalid JSON on the client side?" What is invalid JSON? Can you post a sample of what the JSON looks like?

Comment: The code in my edit is formatted the same as the server side file, with different coordinates. The error I get is "unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" when running the ajax response through JSON.parse.

Comment: Before I bother answering what seems like a syntax problem, are you really sure you want to load "massive" arrays from the server? If it really is a lot of data, then I would load the data dynamically when the user changes layers. Anyway, post what your current json return is please (console output)

Comment: Also, what is your backend? Are you using ASP.NET or something? Or can you just give us a link to whatever source you are calling so we can see it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like (I might be wrong here) that you're calculating the `LatLng` function on client side. This also means that you're sending data like

```
new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368)
```

direclty in JSON file. JSON array can only accept String, Object, Boolean, Null and Numbers.

For `new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368)` to be valid, it needs to be wrapped in quotes.

If you fix that, your JSON will be valid.

Comment: I tried sending a raw array like the simplified example " [0,1,2,3,4] ", however the error arises in JSON.parse and never makes it farther. line 1column 1 is the opening bracket and it says that's where the error is. ultimately I will have the return value of google.maps.LatLng stored instead of declaration (again to prevent client side processing).

Comment: Are you getting JSON as array or string? Because parse will only work if the data is String of array/Object

Comment: I am making an ajax request for the file shown in the examples (that is the exact contents of the file) and running the ajax response through JSON.parse() then passing the result of JSON.parse() to the Google Maps function. It makes it to JSON.parse() and gives me the error. If I don't pass it through JSON.parse() (which I know is incorrect but I tried it anyways I get an error from the Google Maps function saying it's an invalid array.

Comment: Are you getting error similar to `VM5810:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position`?